# The inline tag editor's progress indicator is stretched out

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

While I'm doing the inline tag edit by clicking on the "Edit tags" (privilege earned [when reaching 10,000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) on a post, there is a loader image which is briefly visible. However, the loader image is very big and not looking good.

I was able to reproduce this issue on the following browsers:

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 87.0 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) |
| Zoom | 100% |

GIF for the same:

[image: loader issue]

Comment: I was able to duplicate this in FF84.0.0. For ease of duplication, you can do `StackExchange.helpers.addSpinner('.post-taglist')` in the JavaScript console, which will display the same element, but won't immediately remove it. There should probably be a `max-height` applied to the `ajax-loader` class.

Comment: No repro on FF on Mac

Comment: Can briefly see it. It's easier to reproduce if you're on a slower Internet connection (use Chrome Developer Tools to simulate).

Comment: @Makyen max height might help, but the original gif is only 4 pixels height. It stretch due to the grid design SE decided to use, which cause elements to take 100% width and height. Proper fix would be to fix the grid.

Comment: Yeah now I see it too.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on Chrome on android, albeit being in a blink of an eye.

Comment: Regression of [Loading animation on edit screen is stretched vertically and appears as vertical lines](/q/314686/289905), but even worse this time.

Comment: Still happening!

Comment: I just observed the same bug with Safari on a Mac, after updating to macOS Ventura 13.3.

Comment: Apparently this [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392637/edit-tags-loading-indicator-styling-bug#392637)  still persist in 2023...