# What is the purpose and name of these big gray bands moving left to right when I try to save a tags edit?

Tags: support, tags, edits, user-interface

I see [Loader issue with inline tag editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358602) but here I am not reporting an issue; *I am asking what it's called and what it's for*

When I edit the tags on a question using the tag editor, sometimes I see a display of large gray bands scrolling from right to left. Once the edit is accepted they disappear.

**Question:** What is the purpose and name of these big gray bands moving left to right when I try to save a tags edit?

Details if relevant: It's generally on my old laptop: macOS 10.11.6 and Chrome version 91.0.... (incognito mode)

[image: big gray bands moving left-to-right when I save tag edits]

Comment: I think there was a similar question a while ago. I believe it's supposed to be a loader gif but for some reason it's scaled up a lot. Its size should be smaller than the tag input box.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I see it, I want to know what it's for and what it's called.

Comment: It is called progress-dots.gif. It is obtained by `GET https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/progress-dots.gif` when clicking the "Edit tags" button.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this is more of a [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com) question, but anyway: it's a progress indicator, or more specifically, an [indeterminate progress bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_bar).

This is how it's intended to look like:
[image]

It's purpose is to let you know the system registered your click on the save/edit button, but it needs a while to save the changes or prepare the edit mode.

Comment: i dont know how it can be more obvious

Comment: It's rather obvious except if you've never seen (or don't remember) anything but the buggy version. Bugs like that are the reason for initiative like [Facebook's 2G Tuesdays](https://marketrealist.com/2018/01/facebook-uses-2g-tuesdays-improve-products/).

Comment: I would suggest updated terminology: 1.) It's a loading indicator (also known as a spinner) 2.) It's there to indicate that the browser on OP's computer had initiated a "web-request" towards SE's server, but it had not yet received the server's response (which could confirm that saving the edited tag into the database on SE's server was indeed successful).

Comment: While I have learnt something new from the term "Indeterminate progress bar", I feel I would use them for a special subset of download actions, in which the download protocol — from the server's side — does not reveal the file-size of the downloaded object up front, thus making drawing a "determinate progress bar" unfeasible. These indeterminate downloads tend to be the ones that use a tech called "streaming" (though talking about this latter part is not my forte).