# 'Edit tags' loading indicator styling bug

Tags: bug, tags, design

When pressing the 'Edit tags' button, most of the times the loading indicators get some absurd styling:

> [image: gif of styling issue in 'edit tags']

<sub>[Other question/GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AInX.gif)</sub>

Comment: This seems to happen when loading the loading from the server takes a while. The loading indicator is oversized for the element it's indicating. I guess easy to simulate by throttling the connection.